# C++ initializing array based on constructor parameters

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor

Hi im new to C++ and I'm having a problem with initializing an array based on constructor parameters.

What I'm trying to do in C#:

```
class Surface
{
    public int[] pixels;

    public Surface(int w, int h)
    {
        pixels = new int[w * h];
    }
}
```

What I have right now in C++:

```
class Surface
{
    private:
        GLuint pixels[];
    public:
        Surface(int w, int h) {pixels(w * h) } //Initialize pixels based on width and height
        ~Surface();

};
```

Thanks

Comment: You're not being very clear on what the problem is exactly. Are you asking about the compilation errors? Also, a big problem I see in both versions is that you're not saving the width and height, only the total surface area.

Comment: `pixels = new int[w*h]` This will initialize the array on heap.

Comment: @JanVanBergen It would be a good idea to edit your question to make it more clear on what exactly you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a plain pointer definition for `pixels`:

```
class Surface {
    private:
        GLuint* pixels; // <<<<<<
    public:
        Surface(int w, int h) : pixels(new GLuint[w * h]) {}
        ~Surface();
};
```

---

Or even better a `std::vector<GLuint>` member:

```
class Surface {
    private:
        std::vector<GLuint> pixels; // <<<<<<
    public:
        Surface(int w, int h) : pixels(w * h,0) {}
        ~Surface();
};
```

---

or at least a `std::unique_ptr<GLuint[]>`:

```
class Surface {
    private:
        std::unique_ptr<GLuint[]> pixels; // <<<<<<
    public:
        Surface(int w, int h) : pixels(new GLuint[w * h]) {}
        ~Surface();
};
```

Comment: The `unique_ptr` version will invoke UB when it calls the wrong version of `delete`.

Comment: @juanchopanza Would my edit fix it? Otherwise I probably should remove that part completely at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `std::vector`:

```
#include  <vector>

class Surface
{
    private:
        std::vector<GLuint> pixels;
    public:
        Surface(int w, int h) : pixels(w * h) { }
};
```

If you use `new[]` instead, you have to manage the allocation, copying, and freeing of the array manually:

```
class Surface
{
    private:
        GLuint *pixels;
        int numPixels;
    public:
        Surface(int w, int h) : numPixels(w*h), pixels(new GLuint [numPixels]) { }
        Surface(const Surface &src) : numPixels(src.numPixels), pixels(new GLuint[numPixels]) { std::copy(src.pixels, src.pixels + numPixels, pixels); }
        ~Surface() { delete[] pixels; }
        Surface& operator=(const Surface &lhs) { Surface temp(lhs); std::swap(temp.pixels, pixels); std::swap(temp.numPixels, numPixels); return *this; }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++ static array size has to be compile-time constant.

Solution is to use dynamic array, since it's size doesn't have to be compile-time constant.

Even better solution is to use some abstraction over dynamic array such as `std::vector`.

Answer (score -1):

There's no such thing as a variable-length array in C++. All arrays have a fixed length. Since you need a variable-length array, you must use a `std::vector`, instead.

```
std::vector<GLuint> pixels;
```

And the construct can use `resize()` to size the vector:

```
Surface(int w, int h) {
    pixels.resize(w * h);
}
```

Comment: A vector has a constructor that takes a count as input. As such, you can initialize the vector in the initialization list instead of with `resize ()` in the constructor body.